# Number Safety Checking ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, numbers

Why the statement returns **false** 
`Number.isSafeInteger(-1312321312321.1)`

And the following statement returns **true** `Number.isSafeInteger(-1232312321312321.1)` ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? What do you expect and why?

Comment: what is the range of Number, are you overflowing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first number (-1312321312321.1) is small enough* that the `.1` on the end is retained, so the test fails since the number is not an integer.

The second number (-1232312321312321.1) is just big enough that the `.1` on the end is rounded off. As far as JavaScript is concerned, that number is -1232312321312321 -- an integer. It's also small enough to fit within the safe integer range.

*I mean "big" and "small" in terms of magnitude, ignoring the negative/positive sign.